# spark select column which has double quotes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

my spark data frame has one column like below

```
"drop":{"dropPath":"https://dropserv.content25.ec2.st-av.net/drop?source_id: string (nullable = true)
```

I need to run select query on this, I tried the below command but getting error

```
df.select('"drop":{"dropPath":"https://dropserv.content25.ec2.st-av.net/drop?source_id').show(10)     

error: unclosed character literal
```

my dataframe schema is

scala> df.printSchema()

```
root
 |-- metadata: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- "drop":{"dropPath":"https://dropserv.content25.ec2.st-av.net/drop?source_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- url: string (nullable = true)
```

I tried below thing also but same error

```
  df.select(('`"drop":{"dropPath":"https://mediaserv.media27.ec2.st-av.net/drop?source_id`').show()
```

Comment: try escaping double quotes....       `df.select("drop\":{\"dropPath\":\"https://dropserv.content25.ec2.st-av.net/drop?source_id").show(10)`

Comment: same error  error: unclosed string literal

Answer (score 0):

You can use ` for this.

```
df.select('drop.`dropPath`.`https://dropserv.content25.ec2.st-av.net/drop?source_id`').show(10)
```

Comment: I tried but still there is error ->    <console>:1: error: unclosed quoted identifier
df.select('metadata.`drop`:{`dropPath`:`https://dropserv.media25.ec2.st-av.net/drop?source_id').show(100)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the problem is dot `.` in your column name. When you remove all dots, you will see it works fine.

What you can do to select the column name is this,

```
#Add ` in the start and end of string while selecting.
df.select('`"drop":{"dropPath":"https://dropserv.content25.ec2.st-av.net/drop?source_id`')
```

Comment: I am still getting the error :::::::::-> <console>:1: error: unclosed string literal
df.select('`"drop":{"dropPath":"https://mediaserv.media27.ec2.st-av.net/drop?source_id`')

Comment: Did you include ` inside the string as I said above? I mean first single string ' and after that `.

Comment: ya, I tried, since that ` symbol was not coming, I updated my question check it ..